# Solve the complex system :

Tags: complex-numbers

Find $x$ and $y$ where :
\begin{cases}
ix-(1+i)y=3 \\
(2+i)x+iy=4 & \text{}
\end{cases}

I have used the rectangular form of complex number by expressing $x=(a,b)$ and $y=(c,d)$ and reaching in a system with 4 equations and 4 unknowns in this form :

\begin{cases}
-b=3+c+-d \\
a=d+c \\
2a=4+d+c \\
2b=-c-a \\
\end{cases}

where we get the right answer $x=(\frac{7}{3}, \frac{-4}{3})$ and $y=(\frac{1}{3},2)$

I would like to know if there is any simpler approach with some more clever manipulations cause my solving method is a bit long.

Comment: How did you obtain that $x$ and $y$? From $a=d+c$ and $2a=4+d+c$ we should get $2a=4+a$, and hence $a=4$.

Comment: Actually, the system is incorrect.

Comment: I think it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Cramer rule, evaluating the $2\times2$ determinants in complex numbers.

$$\Delta=\left|\begin{array}&i&-(1+i)\\2+i&i\end{array}\right|=3i$$
and so on.

Comment: is this allowed?

Comment: Try it, won't bite you.

Comment: I thought because the multiplication in complex numbers in not the same as the reals maybe it wouldn't be correct

Comment: @AdmirKullolli: you can redo the proof of Cramers' formulas wholly in complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Just express $x$ as function of $y$ from both equations.
Then set the two expressions to be equal. Then find $y$.

By using this approach I get:
$y=1/3 + 2i$
$x=(7-4i)/3$
So it seems your result is correct.